# Align a button below the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-button

Currently my code places a button at the bottom of the screen:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/main_button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, I wish to align it slightly below the bottom of the screen, so a small part of the button is clipped off (Say, 20%). Ultimately, my end result is that when I tap and drag the button up, it will move up and reveal the entire button, but before that, the bottom part of it is clipped.

---

There are many questions on how to align a button to the bottom of a screen, but I can't seem to find any that aligns it to below the bottom of the screen.

Is there any way to do so, or am I not using the correct search terms?

---

EDIT: From the answers, I tried android:translationY="20dp" and it did not work, but I tried android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp" and it worked for me.

Comment: If you can align it to the bottom, then you can add a top margin to push it off the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `android:translationY="Xdp"` to your button to move it down by X dp.

Alternatively you can create two `LinearLayouts`. One to fill the screen and hold other components and another that contains the button. You can then add `android:layout_below="@id/layout0"` and `android:margin_top="Xdp"` to control how far below the screen the layout with the button should be.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        </LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout0"
            android:margin_top="Xdp"
            android:gravity="center|bottom">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="95dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/main_button"/>
       </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the button:

```
android:translationY="20dp"
```

in your xml, that's moves the view 20 dp's down.